# Subquery parameter as Date in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I was wondering if is possible to get a @stardate and @enddate from a subquery. To be more especific I want to use the values of DUEDATE as parameters in a SSRS report to filter my data
[image]

```
 Select 
  Table1.[No_] AS tNo
 ,Table2.[Date] AS tDate
 ,Table2.[CSource] AS Source

 (Select TOP 1 DATEADD(day,35,Table3.[PDate]) from [Table4] Table4
   inner join [Table5] Table5 ON Table4.[ ILE No_] = Table5.[Entry No_]
   inner join [Table3] Table3 ON Table4.[ ILE No_] = Table3.[Entry No_]
   ) 
   AS DueDate

from [Table1] Table1
inner join [Table2] Table2 ON Table1.[ No_] = Table2.[cNo_]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you asking if you can filter a datset field named DueDate by parameters named @startdate and @enddate?

Comment: You can use the result of a dataset query to set the default value of your parameters, if that's what you are asking?